# PyQtGraph PolyLineROI maxBounds Not Working

Tags: plot, handle, polyline, pyqtgraph

I have a `PolyLineROI` in a `PlotItem` and am trying to limit the handles to moving only within the bounds of the plot. I have tried to use the `maxBounds` argument, but this does not work (the handles still move outside the graph):

**Code:**

```py
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore

app = pg.mkQApp('Plot')

window = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True, size=(400,400), border=False, title='Plot')
plt = window.addPlot(title='Plot')

polyline = pg.PolyLineROI(
    [[0,0], [10,10], [10,30], [30,10]],
    closed=False,
    maxBounds=QtCore.QRectF(0,0,30,30)
)

plt.addItem(polyline)

plt.disableAutoRange('xy')
plt.autoRange()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pg.exec()
```

**Problem:**

[image: Handles_Move_Outside_Graph]

I have seen this question asked on these mailing lists:

1. [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/pyqtgraph/c/MBK8reAYdV8?pli=1)
2. [Mail Archive Google Group](https://www.mail-archive.com/pyqtgraph@googlegroups.com/msg00555.html)

but they don't have any answers and this has not been asked here.

How can I prevent the handles from moving outside the bounds of the graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you must subclass `PolyLineROI` and override `checkPointMove`:

**Code:**

```py
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore

class GraphPolyLine(pg.PolyLineROI):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def checkPointMove(self, handle, pos, modifiers):
        if self.maxBounds is not None:
            pt = self.getViewBox().mapSceneToView(pos)
        
            if not self.maxBounds.contains(pt.x(), pt.y()):
                return False

        return True

app = pg.mkQApp("ROI Examples")

window = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True, size=(400,400), border=False, title='Plot')

plt = window.addPlot(title="Plot")
plt.setMouseEnabled(False, False)  # Disable zoom and pan

polyline = GraphPolyLine(
    [[0,0], [10,10], [10,30], [30,10]],
    closed=False,
    maxBounds = QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 30, 30)
)

plt.addItem(polyline)
plt.disableAutoRange('xy')
plt.autoRange()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pg.exec()
```

**Solution:**

From `pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.ROI`, we see

[image: checkPointMove]

[image: WorkingSolution]